# Получить данные из вложенного словаря Python

Tags: python, json

Нужна ваша помощь.
Имеется словарь:

```
a = 
      {
       "meta": {
          "request": {
             "main_domain_only": false,
             "format": "json",
             "domain": "stroсd.com",
             "start_date": "2019-10-01",
             "end_date": "2020-01-31",
             "limit": null,
             "country": "world",
             "show_verified": true
          },
          "status": "Success",
          "last_updated": "2020-01-31"
       },
       "overview": [
          {
             "domain": "Direct",
             "source_type": "Direct",
             "share": 0.55773467
          },
          {
             "domain": "Google Search",
             "source_type": "Search / Organic",
             "share": 0.2018796
          },
          {
             "domain": "Facebook",
             "source_type": "Social",
             "share": 0.081907906
          },
          {
             "domain": "Google Search",
             "source_type": "Search / Paid",
             "share": 0.035226278
          },
          {
             "domain": "Email",
             "source_type": "Email",
             "share": 0.026017865
          },
          {
             "domain": "Other Sources",
             "source_type": "Other",
             "share": 0.0070781517
          }
       ],
       "visits": 36721
    }
```

Как вывести первые 3 домена? То есть Direct, Google Search, Facebook.

```
print(a["overview"]["domain"][0][0][0:3])
```

Ошибка: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0):

Изначально `a` у вас это JSON. **JSON != Питонскому словарю.**
Чтобы распарсить его, нужно импорировать пакет `json`.

```
a = """ 
    {
   "meta":{
      "request":{
         "main_domain_only":false,
         "format":"json",
         "domain":"stroсd.com",
         "start_date":"2019-10-01",
         "end_date":"2020-01-31",
         "limit":null,
         "country":"world",
         "show_verified":true
      },
      "status":"Success",
      "last_updated":"2020-01-31"
   },
   "overview":[
      {
         "domain":"Direct",
         "source_type":"Direct",
         "share":0.55773467
      },
      {
         "domain":"Google Search",
         "source_type":"Search / Organic",
         "share":0.2018796
      },
      {
         "domain":"Facebook",
         "source_type":"Social",
         "share":0.081907906
      },
      {
         "domain":"Google Search",
         "source_type":"Search / Paid",
         "share":0.035226278
      },
      {
         "domain":"Email",
         "source_type":"Email",
         "share":0.026017865
      },
      {
         "domain":"Other Sources",
         "source_type":"Other",
         "share":0.0070781517
      }
   ],
   "visits":36721
}
"""

import json
domains = [i['domain'] for i in json.loads(a)['overview']][:3]
```

Comment: Спасибо! А без импорта json никак? По индексам просто нельзя?

Comment: @Mer, если мы просто создадим словарь, так как у вас с json'a, то будет ошибка. В Питоне нету `false\true`, есть `False\True`, типа `null` и т.д.